# How to make a dynamic xml file that I can access through js with php

Tags: php, xml

I have a php web scraper that scrapes a site, but what I would like to do is with the data it found to output that as a xml file, which needs to be accessible by javascript. For some reason it is not coming back as a Xml file but just a html file.

Please let me know if I need to make anything clearer.

EDIT(Code Added):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php 
...scraper code...
$link = $html->find('a', 19);

echo'<user>';
echo '<link>'.$link->plaintext.'</link>';
echo'</user>';

?>
```

When I open this I just get the value of $link in html tags.

Comment: Output the XML, it is unclear where your issue is `echo '<xml><element>test</element></xml>';` would be XML. Maybe having issues passing proper headers?

Comment: @user3783243 but when I open the file it does not display it as a normal xml file. Also when I open the inspector the tags are all in a html body tag. Does that not matter?

Comment: No idea what you have, you've not posted any code yet.

Comment: @user3783243 I updated it so it now has code, hopefully that helps.

Comment: You probably just need to set the "Content-type: application/xml" header before you start any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `application/xml` header:

```
<?php header("Content-type: application/xml"); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php

echo'<user>';
echo '<link>'."Plain Text".'</link>';
echo'</user>';
```

Output in Firefox:
[image]

Comment: Perfect this was the fix! I also forgot to close my user tag but realised that just before your solution.